# BERT not exporting my own R functions to Excel

Tags: excel

I have a question about BERT exporting functions to excel. I have downloaded BERT (2.4.4.), the add-in is seen in excel and I can open it. But when I write some code in R (for example if I put some functions in the functions.r folder of BERT), I cant use them unless I source BERT automatically. I would like to create an excel application which would work by clicking on a macro button, that is why opening BERT console is very unpractical. If functions that I write on my own would be exported to excel I imagine I could use them anytime, but they are not, not even TestAdd from BERT file functions.r.

Answer (score 0):

check this topic from BERT troubleshooting topics http://www.bert-toolkit.org/troubleshooting-bert

No R Functions (or Julia Functions)

If BERT seems to work (the console opens up, there’s a shell) but you have no R functions in Excel, it might be because your home directory (where we install the functions file) is on a network drive. We’re looking into this issue, but for the time being, try moving the functions directory to a local drive.

You can change this configuration in the BERT console, from the menu item View > Preferences. Change the value of functionsDirectory:

// files in this directory will be loaded at startup and reloaded
// when changed. the same directory is used for all languages.

"functionsDirectory": "c:\my\local\directory"

Save the Preferences file and make sure it says “Preferences OK” in the status bar. Then restart Excel for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, I have changed the functionDirectory, but do I also have to change the R and library paths? Because something still isn't ok. I can not execute the functions.r script in BERT and the R shell isn't seen.

Comment: I think something very similar to https://github.com/sdllc/Basic-Excel-R-Toolkit/issues/91 is happening, I also get the same error ( Application-defined or object-defined error) when I try to run a macro which contains:     Range("E5").Value = Application.Run("BERT.Call", "sestej", 1, 2, 3), shere "sestej" is my defined function included in functions.r file.